# Angular ng-click directive not working in IE 11

Tags: javascript, angularjs, internet-explorer-11

I've got a problem where a simple ng-click function is working in all browsers except IE10 and 11 (haven't been able to check Edge yet.)

Here's the directive:

```
$scope.showMoreDetails = false;
  $scope.toggleMoreDetails = function() {
    $scope.showMoreDetails = !$scope.showMoreDetails;
  };
```

And here's the call:

```
<a data-ng-if="!showMoreDetails" data-ng-click="toggleMoreDetails()"></a>
<a data-ng-if="showMoreDetails" data-ng-click="toggleMoreDetails()"></a>
```

Thanks for your help, I'm at wit's end.

Answer (score 0):

Probably because you need a valid href in your anchor tag

Answer (score 0):

Your tags should look like this:

```
<a href="" data-ng-if="!showMoreDetails" data-ng-click="toggleMoreDetails()"></a>
<a href="" data-ng-if="showMoreDetails" data-ng-click="toggleMoreDetails()"></a>
```